# How to handle conflicting responses to comment flags

Tags: support, declined-flags, comment-flags

I recently flagged a comment for moderator attention, pointing out that the user regularly posted such comments, and asked whether what they were doing was an acceptable practice. The flag was subsequently marked as helpful and the comment was deleted.

Taking encouragement from this, the next day I flagged all the other comments I could find by the same user that had the same problem. Unfortunately, the responses I got this time were somewhat conflicting. All of the comments I flagged were deleted, but at the same time, some of them were also declined! This has now left me wondering whether I did the right thing or not.

To make matters worse, the first question I looked at later on the same day has yet another series of problematic comments by the same user. Should I keep flagging them or not? I would have thought that after all the flags I raised previously, a moderator might have contacted the user and asked them to stop what they were doing. But for whatever reason, this doesn't seem to have happened. Could a moderator please therefore advise me on what should be done next? (I will assume that it's obvious from my recent flagging history which user it is I am referring to).

Comment: I would flag one post of the user, explain the pattern/nature of the comments and state that you raised this issue earlier but didn't stop the comments. Using a post flag allows a mod to respond to you if they feel you should stop flagging that. On comment flags they can't provide feedback. And on post flags you have 500 charcters to explain an issue, on comment flags only 150. After that, move on.

Comment: Don't target individual users. If you find cases of it naturally through browsing questions, that's fine. but targeting is bad.

Comment: You probably had different moderators handle each flag.

Comment: @KevinB. The majority of them were comments I've encountered before, since I look at most of the questions in some tags with relatively low traffic. The comments were becoming increasingly annoying to both me and other users, so I decided to do something about it. I don't think targeting is necessarily always bad. Sometimes you need to look at the whole history of behaviour to make sure you're taking the right action.

Comment: @rene I don't think I've ever used a post-flag, so that's useful to know. How does a moderator reply - direct to your inbox?

Comment: @ekhumoro no, you have to keep an eye on your flag history, the same place where you found your declined flags

Comment: @rene Thanks. If I'd known that post-flags were handled differently, I probably would've gone about things differently right from the start.

Comment: we can't comment on declined comment flags. But unless you're _really_ abusing the system (in which case you'd get a moderator message), having your flags declined or marked as helpful doesn't change much.